# load test specific pages

Tags: apache2, load-testing, stress-testing

I've read about load testing and the tools that can be used to implement it on a web application.
I'm using **apache ab**. Let it be any other tool, but my question is how do you load test specific pages without actually logging into the web application ?

How do you know the response time of each page by simply using **" ab -k -n 500 -c 10 http://abc.xyz.com/"** when the real one to be tested is **" ab -k -n 500 -c 10 http://abc.xyz.com/index.html"** which is accessible only if you log in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first get the authorization cookie manually (using [curl](http://ask.metafilter.com/18923/How-do-you-handle-authentication-via-cookie-with-CURL), for example), then just add it to headers. We use [Yandex.Tank](https://github.com/yandex-load/yandex-tank) for most of our load testing tasks. Here's an example of load.ini for your case:

```
[phantom]
address = abc.xyz.com
rps_schedule = line (1, 120, 15) const (120, 10m)
header_http = 1.1
headers = [Host: abc.xyz.com]
  [Connection: close]
  [Cookie:<here goes auth cookie>]
uris=/index.html
```

I think you could also do something similar with ab or jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

> Let it be any other tool, but my question is how do you load test specific pages without actually logging into the web application ?

The short answer is: No, you can not.  If you could, then the application would have a big security hole, right?

You need to login, get the authorization token / session ID (probably a cookie) and send that in future requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test with a large number of concurrent virtual clients, each doing login and a bunch of actions, you may want to try some performance test tools that can emulate a real user. On [NetGend](http://www.netgend.com) test platform, the following example script will emulate a user by filling the html form and do some actions. (NetGend use javascript syntax)

```
quickForm("http://www.example.com/login?", ["jsmith", "abc123"]);
//do action after login
//get a list of productIDS
prodId = randElement(productIDS);
action(http,"http://www.example.com/view?product=${prodId}");
```

NetGend test platform doesn't only make interaction with web site easier, it can emulate a large number of clients - for example, you can feed it with a csv file with 50,000 user/password combo.

If you have time, you may want to check out many [blogs](http://perftestingng.blogspot.com/) on many test scenarios.